# What will be the best mysql configuration for 12 core processor 128 gb ram ssd 160gb hdd

Tags: mysql

What will be the best mysql configuration for 12 core processor, 128 GB ram sized 160gb HDD.
Mysqltuner.pl result!

-------- General Statistics --------------------------------------------------

```
[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.1.71
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture
```

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------

```
[--] Status: -Archive -BDB -Federated +InnoDB -ISAM -NDBCluster
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 79M (Tables: 124)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 5M (Tables: 339)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 346
```

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------

```
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
```

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------

```
[--] Up for: 13h 37m 35s (94M q [1K qps], 9M conn, TX: 46B, RX: 22B)
[--] Reads / Writes: 56% / 44%
[--] Total buffers: 34.0M global + 2.8M per thread (1000 max threads)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 2.7G (2% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/94M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 34% (346/1000)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 8.0M/35.1M
[OK] Key buffer hit rate: 97.9% (1B cached / 38M reads)
[!!] Query cache is disabled
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 10M sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 3360
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 49% (4M on disk / 9M total)
[!!] Thread cache is disabled
[!!] Table cache hit rate: 0% (214 open / 15M opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 4% (225/5K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 95% (94M immediate / 99M locks)
[OK] InnoDB data size / buffer pool: 5.4M/8.0M
```

-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:

```
Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
Enable the slow query log to troubleshoot bad queries
Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
When making adjustments, make tmp_table_size/max_heap_table_size equal
Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries without LIMIT clauses
Set thread_cache_size to 4 as a starting value
Increase table_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits
```

Variables to adjust:

```
query_cache_size (>= 8M)
join_buffer_size (> 128.0K, or always use indexes with joins)
tmp_table_size (> 16M)
max_heap_table_size (> 16M)
thread_cache_size (start at 4)
table_cache (> 64)
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question. In fact, it doesn't look like a question at all.

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://tools.percona.com. It has a wizard where you type in your server's hardware configuration, and it recommends MySQL tuning parameters.

It also asks questions about your workload and size of database, and so on. You didn't consider these details in your question above, but they are important things to consider when tuning MySQL.